# duplicate entry for key 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language' when manually inserting joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Joomla 3

I am trying to manually insert some records into `#__menu`. Since for most fields I can just use the value that other records have, I am trying to get a stdObject from an existing record and insert it back to the table. Before that, I need to take care of the possible key duplicate. I read the table structure, and besides `id`, I find field `lft` and `rgt` seem to have to be unique. So the following is what I try:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `#__menu` WHERE id = 203';
$db->setQuery($sql);
$example = $db->loadObjectList()[0];
unset($example->id);                     
unset($example->lft);
unset($example->rgt);

$db->insertObject('#__menu',$example);
```

The error message I get is

> Duplicate entry '0-1-001-*' for key
>   'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language'
>
> SQL=INSERT INTO `#__menu`
>   (`menutype`,`title`,`alias`,`note`,`path`,`link`,`type`,`published`,`parent_id`,`level`,`component_id`,`checked_out`,`checked_out_time`,`browserNav`,`access`,`img`,`template_style_id`,`params`,`home`,`language`,`client_id`)
>   VALUES ('hidden','test','001','','001','index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=1','component','1','1','1','10125','0','0000-00-00
>   00:00:00','0','1','
>   ','0','{\"menu-anchor_title\":\"\",\"menu-anchor_css\":\"\",\"menu_image\":\"\",\"menu_text\":1,\"menu_show\":1,\"page_title\":\"\",\"show_page_heading\":\"\",\"page_heading\":\"\",\"pageclass_sfx\":\"\",\"menu-meta_description\":\"\",\"menu-meta_keywords\":\"\",\"robots\":\"\",\"secure\":0}','0','*','0')

I don't understand why there is a key called 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language', it sure is not one of the table's fields. Googling it returns some result, but it seems to me none of them is related to my problem.

Comment: Can you give us the output of 'SHOW CREATE TABLE __menu'?

Comment: http://p.nycweb.io/1.png  @NeilMasters

Comment: Ok try the 'menu' table, its more for your benefit than mine as it highlights the key :) You are manually inserting a row and receiving a key error. The Key is a combination between the alias,client_id, parent_id and language so you can not have two rows with the same combination.

Comment: Thanks. Now I start to understand what is happening

Comment: select * from menu where client_id = {clientId} and parent_id = {parentId} and alias={alias} and lanuage={language}. If you substitute the values from what you are trying to insert you will get the existing row.

Comment: I thought it was all about you can't have two menu items that have same `alias` under same `parent` and `language`. However, I change the `alias` and run the code again, I am still getting the same error message

Comment: I have two existing records, and for those fields in the combination, only `alias` of these two are different. they are "001" and "002", I set the property `alias` of my object to "003" and try to insert it, but I am still getting the error message, `Duplicate entry '0-1-003-*' for key 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language'`

Comment: Is language meant to be *?

Comment: for the other two existing records, yes, both are `*`

Comment: shenkwen, dump a show create table and a select * to a pastebin for us to look at, we can also use that to duplicate the error. FYI the table name is t8glm_menu according to your screenshot.

Comment: I think my code is working now. Turns out I just need to change the value of `alias` and the record was successfully inserted.

Comment: For the benefit of future researchers `$db->loadObjectList()[0]` is better expressed as `$db->loadObject()` https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObject.28.29  In cases where no qualifying rows were found, there will be no `[0]` key to reference and this will make php bark at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought that I would write up an answer as shenkwen commented that he googled for an answer and found nothing helpful.

The error that OP is seeing as caused by him manually inserting a row but there is a multiple column key on the menu table. The key is a combination of *client_id*, *parent_id*, *alias* and *language*.

You can not have two rows which share those same values. As noted in the comments from OP he was duplicating the alias.

Comment: My code is working now.  Thanks for teaching me about combination key, it is new to me. 
Now I have a minor problem, what are those `lft` and `rgt` fields about? I found that for other records they are incrementing, but for my newly inserted record, they are both 0. Will this create any problem in the future?

Comment: As far as I recall(its been a while since I used joomla) they are use to indicate how deeply nested they are so you can create submenus. https://docs.joomla.org/Tables/menu